# Use the variable of a for loop in a property name

Tags: objective-c

I want to use the variable of a for loop in a property name, example:

```
@interface
{
Player *rival1, *rival2, *rival3;
}

int number;
for (number=1; number<=3; number++){
    rival+number = [[Player alloc] init]; //The compiler accepts this.
    rival+number.name = @"";
    //^This line gives the error: "use of undeclared identifier 'rival'"
    //For the first loop, I want it work like: rival1.name = @"";
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: See my answer below. This isn't a clean way to approach this, but you can generate a string from your integer and use SelectorWithString to dynamically call the setters for the respective properties.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a particularly clean way of approaching this, but to answer the question as you've posed it:

```
- (void)generateRivals
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        NSString *propertySetString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"setRival%d", i];
        Rival *rival = [[Rival alloc] init];
        [self performSelector:@selector(NSSelectorFromString(propertySetString)) withObject:rival];
    }

}
```

We create a selector (I haven't tested this, but it should work in theory) that corresponds to the getter for the property instance represented by i.

Based on comments you've added, it seems like what you really want is a variable number of players (perhaps not exceeding a certain number) with the ability to reference them individually.

Architecturally, rather than create properties pointing to each respective rival, put them all in an array (and keep it as a property on your class). So you'd create them like this:

```
- (void)generateRivals:(NSUInteger)numberOfRivals
{

    NSMutableArray *rivalsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numberOfRivals];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRivals; i++)
    {
        Rival *rival = [[Rival alloc] init];
        [rivalsArray insertObject:rival atIndex:i];
    }

    [self setRivalsArray:rivals];
}
```

Then, when you need to access a particular rival, call a method like this, which will return the rival at the index number you pass:

```
- (Rival *)rivalWithNumber:(NSUInteger)number
{
    return [[self rivalsArray] objectAtIndex:number];
}
```

Comment: For the clean way you have done it, I don't quite understand the *player in Players part. The reason I was using a variable is because I may not was to allocate all of the rivals, just the number specified before hand in the number variable. Is it possible to do that with the clean method you have shown?

Comment: the problem with the clean approach is, that objects must be created before they can be but into the array for the enumeration

Comment: @vikingosegundo - that's true. You could put null values in as placeholders, but I'll remove that part of the answer.

Comment: @PappaSmalls See updated answer. Don't create properties for each rival -- put them all in an array, and then use a method to access them by index.

Answer (score 0):

you cant create the properties variable names on the fly and use it, as the names get lost during compilation

you can put them in an array and enumerate over it

```
Player rival1 = [[Player alloc] init];
Player rival2 = [[Player alloc] init];
Player rival3 = [[Player alloc] init];

for (Player *p in @[rival1, rival2, rival3]) {
    p.name = @"";
}
```

---

probably the best way would be to maintain the rivales in the array from the beginning

```
@interface …
@property(strong) NSArray *rivals;
@end

@implementation …

//in some useful method, like initializer
_rivals = [NSMutableArray array]
for (int i = 0; i < 3 ++i){
    //create player and add to array
}

@end
```

---

You might want to look into [Key Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html).

You need to create properties for your rivals

```
@interface …

@property(strong) Player *rival1;
@property(strong) Player *rival2;
@property(strong) Player *rival3;

@end

@implementation …

-(id)init…
{
    if(self = [super init…]){
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i) {
            Player *rival = [[Player alloc] init];
            rival.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"rival%d", i];
            [self setValue: rival forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rival%d", i]];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Agreed about it not being worth the hassle, but it actually wouldn't be all that hard using key value coding.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running a `for` loop to set the names of the players to `@""` just add the line
     `name = @""`  in your `init` method of your `Player` class. It's faster and more practical than to write a `for` loop. You can also create a method like

```
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)initName{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
      name = initNane;
    }
    return self;
}
```

to set the name of your player at the moment it's created. Although if you want absolutely a `for` loop, you can use the method posted by vikingosegundo previously.